# How to upgrade Rails 4.2.4 to Rails 5.1.0.rc1 API project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I've got a project that uses Rails 4.2.4, Mongoid 4 and I'd like to upgrade to Rails 5.1.0.rc1 and Mongoid 6.1.0.

I've followed the instructions [here] (http://railsapps.github.io/updating-rails.html) however when I run the command `bundle update` I get the following error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rack":
In Gemfile:
rails (= 5.1.0.rc1) was resolved to 5.1.0.rc1, which depends on
  actionpack (= 5.1.0.rc1) was resolved to 5.1.0.rc1, which depends on
    rack (~> 2.0)

sinatra (>= 1.3.0) was resolved to 1.3.0, which depends on
  rack (~> 1.3)
```

Any ideas of why?

Comment: Why do you have sinatra in your Gemfile, do you need that in your project?

Comment: @Iceman There are gems that for instance have admin UIs that depend on sinatra. Those UIs are generally mounted as separate rack apps somewhere in your routes. I think Sidekiq does that for example.

Comment: To try to give some feedback to the actual question: Since you depend on something that depends on sinatra, and that gets resolved to sinatra 1.3.0, which in turn depend on rack ~> 1.3 (which roughly means any rack version that starts with 1.x where x >= 3), that means that you cannot just upgrade your rails version. Since rails 5.1 depends on rack ~> 2.0, you need to upgrade the version of sinatra you depend on. If you want to upgrade to an rc version of rails, I guess you can upgrade to sinatra 2.0.rc2 (which is the latest right now) as well.

Comment: @Iceman It is indeed for Sidekiq

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to the latest sinatra version and see if that works? I don't follow sinatra much so I don't know whether it's completely backwards-compatible.

Comment: I have removed the Rack dependency and managed to upgrade the rest. Now I need to work out how to add it back. But at least I managed to upgrade. Thanks!